# How to use npm file-storage package?

Tags: files, nodejs, storage, npm, javascript

I learn Javascript and don't even know, how exactly use FileStorage object.

```
var storage = new FileStorage(...); // supply valid credentials
```

The package link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-storage

What means "supply valid credentials"?

Answer (score 0):

You can see examples in the site documentation.

For example if you are using ftp you can:

```
var user='my_user'
var password='123456789'
var host='my_host'
var path='temp/backups'

var url=`ftp://${user}:${password}@${host}/${path}`
var storage = new FileStorage(url);
```

Formats at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-storage#url-string--supported-connections

Comment: Thanks a lot! But can you explain to me please, may I use PHPMyAdmin as my host and what is 'temp/backups' stays for?